# Evaporation of sample solvent and redissolving

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

When I conduct a synthesis, after some workups, I usually evaporate large amount of solvent using rotovap, recover compounds sticked to the wall of the flask to the glass vial using small amount of solvent, and finally evaporate all residual solvent using vacuum oven (usually at low temperature about 20~30 ℃ and apply vacuum gradually overnight). After the solvent is completely evaporated, I usually get gooey gel-like compound that is sticked to the bottom of the vial.

[image: sample vial]

I have two questions:

1. I have never obtained powder-like sample after evaporating the
   solvent. But I have a few experience in organic synthesis, so does
   the formation of gel-like form rather than powder form depend on the
   characteristics of the compounds, not the evaporating method?
   Actually, I have once obtained gel-like sample containing large amount of
   unreacted starting materials, even though that material was weighed as powder
   form at the beginning. How can I get the powder form rather than gel-like form when I evaporate the solvent? Does the evaporating method matter?
2. After I evaporate all the solvent, I try to redissolve the sample
   with the same solvent, but it is not readily redissolved although I
   use similar amount. Usually it takes some time and heat. But why? It was readily dissolved in the workup stages. Is this
   because that the sample is sticked to the bottom of the vial?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what exactly is being dried. Unless you are dealing with ionic liquids, I'd expect powder from the *salt*, not necessarily the organic substance itself. You might want to try alternative methods such as [lyophilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-drying) (takes talking with biochem people), or use vapor diffusion crystallization (takes hours (if very lucky)/days/weeks).

Comment: @andselisk I wondered if my evaporating method is generally not appropriate for obtaining powder form of the sample. Solvent I use is common organic solvents like toluene, dichloromethane, ethyl acetate, etc.

Comment: @andselisk Do you have any opinion about question 2? I have almost always faced that problem.

Comment: One of the common reasons for a lack of crystallization is impurities / trace impurities, including water, salts, can cause these problems. 
Again for crystallizations for solids is to dissolve in a warm solvent with a minimum volume. Once it is dissolved, very slowly adding a solvent which does not dissolve it (usually polarity based choices) and slowly cool it. In such cases, often pure crystals can be obtained.

Comment: If your compound is brand new, then you have no clue whether the compound is supposed to be a solid or a liquid and its color is not known either. Let us assume that you were expecting a solid, based on known and similarly structured compounds.

The meaning of purity is quite different in different branches. What is pure for an organic chemist (on the basis of NMR etc.) is quite impure for an analytical/physical chemist. So purity is the key to successful crystallization.

Comment: The most obvious factors are poor solubility and low area of contact of viscous goo with the solvent. Also, the substance might get oxidized with air and you are dissolving a layer of something else that might be less soluble. Storing your substances under argon/nitrogen won't hurt. You can try using sonic bath to speed up dissolving if your substance is stable enough.

Comment: @AChem and andselisk, Thank you for the advices.

Comment: It would be most helpful if the compound in question were identified. Crystals of some complex compound with a low melting point will naturally tend to oil out when evaporated to dryness from a powerful solvent - especially with contaminating ingredients, like unreacted starting materials. And a high mw non-crystalline goo will be resistant to redissolution because each molecule will be immersed in the gooiness of other molecules and won't be exposing much of itself - it'll be like a herd of buffaloes protecting its calves from a pack of wolves by circling up.

Comment: @JamesGaidis Its structure has thiophene and aza-crown. These two compounds have low melting point, so your explanation makes sense. In fact it is not purified yet, I was investigating which eluent should I use for column. Thank you.

Comment: Also, looking at your vial, I'd say it is micro scale synthesis. So, tiny solvent trap with in matrix may not be easily removed so always seems oily. Ask some natural product chemists. :-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thank you for the advice.